# Prove: There are integers $m$ and $n$ such $m - n = n + m$

Tags: solution-verification, computer-science

Prove the following existential statements. Use Constructive Proof. There are integers $m$ and $n$ such $m - n = n + m$

Can I say $m=1$ and $n=0$ therefore $m-n=1+0=1$ and $n+m=0+1=1$.

Comment: Yes, that is a constructive solution.

Answer (score 1):

With Construction Proof, it is an existence proof. By this you want to show that $\exists x(Px)$, basically saying you want to show there is an $x$ that makes $P(x)$ true. So yes, what you have found is true. Saying you found a pair $m=1, n=0$ completes the existence proof.